# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement RTE '-2147217900 (80040e14)':

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have tried paring the strSQL back to just one field and everything works.  As soon as I add a second field I start getting the error.  This tells me that references are correct.  I've tried a lot of different spacing around the ()'s with no luck either.

```
?strSQL
INSERT INTO tbl_buyer_column (ship_id, aels_id, buyer_wss, column, date_created)VALUES(23, 13, K, 1, #04/17/2015#)



Public Sub fun_insert_into(lngship_id As Long, lngAels_id As Long, strBuyer_wss As String, lngColumn As Long, datDate_created As Date)

Dim strSQL As String
Dim adoCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoCmd As ADODB.Command
Set adoCon = CurrentProject.Connection
Set adoCmd = New ADODB.Command

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_buyer_column (ship_id, aels_id, buyer_wss, column, date_created)" & _
     "VALUES(" & lngship_id & ", " & lngAels_id & ", " & strBuyer_wss & ", " & lngColumn & ", " & SQLDate(datDate_created) & ")"

    With adoCmd
        .ActiveConnection = adoCon
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .Execute
    End With

adoCon.Close
Set adoCon = Nothing
Set adoCmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Column` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#C).  That may be the source of the syntax error.  And, if so, you can avoid that error by enclosing the field name in square brackets.  Better yet, rename the field with a non-reserved word if possible.

If that suggestion does eliminate the first error, you can avoid another later error by adding quotes around the character *K* in the `VALUES` list.

Test this as a new query in the Access query designer.  If it works correctly, adjust your VBA code to produce the same `INSERT` statement text.

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_buyer_column (ship_id, aels_id, buyer_wss, [column], date_created)
VALUES (23, 13, 'K', 1, #04/17/2015#)
```

Also note you could use a parameter query for the `INSERT`.  One benefit of that approach is you could avoid problems due to value delimiters.

Comment: Not to disagree with anything you said, but in most cases it's probably preferable to avoid using reserved words in the first place.

Comment: Needed both [ ] and ' around buyer_wss.